# How can i make this responsive and only 5 cards in row?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-5

make this responsive and only 5 cards in a row.
I tried this but not working what should I add?
all I want it to change number of item in a row according to size and hold max 5 element in a row

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Tours</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="3destination_style.css">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                Barrackpore
               </div>
               <p>
                  Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    
         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                Hooghly
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                South 24 parganas 
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                North 24 parganas
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                Kolkata 
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                North 24 parganas
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                North 24 parganas
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                North 24 parganas
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                North 24 parganas
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                North 24 parganas
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                North 24 parganas
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                North 24 parganas
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                North 24 parganas
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                North 24 parganas
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                North 24 parganas
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                North 24 parganas
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                North 24 parganas
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                North 24 parganas
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
html,body{
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background: #1d222b;
  text-align: center;
}
.container{
  padding: 0 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.card{
  height: 280px;
  max-width: 350px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  background: white;
  transition: 0.4s;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.card:hover{
  height: 470px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.card .img{
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
.card .img img{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.card .top-text{
  padding: 5px;
}
.card .top-text .name{
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #202020;
}
.card .top-text p{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #007bff;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.card .bottom-text{
  padding: 0 20px 10px 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.1s;
}
.card:hover .bottom-text{
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.card .bottom-text .text{
  text-align: justify;
}
.card .bottom-text .btn{
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-align: left;
}
.card .bottom-text .btn a{
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #000;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-flex;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
.card .bottom-text .btn a:hover{
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 978px) {
  .container{
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .card{
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 20px 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide HTML.

Answer (score 0):

i added this to your css

```css
.container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 1rem;
}
```

now there is 4 rows (pretty close to what you want)

and is also responsive!
[image: 4rows]

### final result

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap');
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    background: #1d222b;
    text-align: center;
}

.container {
    padding: 0 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 2em;
}

.card {
    height: 280px;
    max-width: 350px;
    margin: 0 20px;
    background: white;
    transition: 0.4s;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.card:hover {
    height: 470px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.card .img {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}

.card .img img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.card .top-text {
    padding: 5px;
}

.card .top-text .name {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #202020;
}

.card .top-text p {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #007bff;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.card .bottom-text {
    padding: 0 20px 10px 20px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    background: white;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: 0.1s;
}

.card:hover .bottom-text {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.card .bottom-text .text {
    text-align: justify;
}

.card .bottom-text .btn {
    margin: 10px 0;
    text-align: left;
}

.card .bottom-text .btn a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #000;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-flex;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.card .bottom-text .btn a:hover {
    transform: scale(0.9);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 978px) {
    .container {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .card {
        max-width: 700px;
        margin: 20px 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tours</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="3destination_style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
                <div class="name">
                    Barrackpore
                </div>
                <p>
                    Area Description
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
                <div class="text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
                </div>
                <div class="btn">
                    <a href="#">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
                <div class="name">
                    Hooghly
                </div>
                <p>
                    Area Description
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
                <div class="text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
                </div>
                <div class="btn">
                    <a href="#">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
                <div class="name">
                    South 24 parganas
                </div>
                <p>
                    Area Description
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
                <div class="text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
                </div>
                <div class="btn">
                    <a href="#">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
                <div class="name">
                    North 24 parganas
                </div>
                <p>
                    Area Description
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
                <div class="text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
                </div>
                <div class="btn">
                    <a href="#">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
                <div class="name">
                    Kolkata
                </div>
                <p>
                    Area Description
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
                <div class="text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
                </div>
                <div class="btn">
                    <a href="#">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
                <div class="name">
                    North 24 parganas
                </div>
                <p>
                    Area Description
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
                <div class="text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
                </div>
                <div class="btn">
                    <a href="#">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
                <div class="name">
                    North 24 parganas
                </div>
                <p>
                    Area Description
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
                <div class="text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
                </div>
                <div class="btn">
                    <a href="#">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
                <div class="name">
                    North 24 parganas
                </div>
                <p>
                    Area Description
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
                <div class="text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
                </div>
                <div class="btn">
                    <a href="#">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
                <div class="name">
                    North 24 parganas
                </div>
                <p>
                    Area Description
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
                <div class="text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
                </div>
                <div class="btn">
                    <a href="#">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
                <div class="name">
                    North 24 parganas
                </div>
                <p>
                    Area Description
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
                <div class="text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
                </div>
                <div class="btn">
                    <a href="#">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
                <div class="name">
                    North 24 parganas
                </div>
                <p>
                    Area Description
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
                <div class="text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
                </div>
                <div class="btn">
                    <a href="#">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
                <div class="name">
                    North 24 parganas
                </div>
                <p>
                    Area Description
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
                <div class="text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
                </div>
                <div class="btn">
                    <a href="#">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
                <div class="name">
                    North 24 parganas
                </div>
                <p>
                    Area Description
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
                <div class="text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
                </div>
                <div class="btn">
                    <a href="#">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
                <div class="name">
                    North 24 parganas
                </div>
                <p>
                    Area Description
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
                <div class="text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
                </div>
                <div class="btn">
                    <a href="#">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
                <div class="name">
                    North 24 parganas
                </div>
                <p>
                    Area Description
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
                <div class="text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
                </div>
                <div class="btn">
                    <a href="#">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
                <div class="name">
                    North 24 parganas
                </div>
                <p>
                    Area Description
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
                <div class="text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
                </div>
                <div class="btn">
                    <a href="#">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
                <div class="name">
                    North 24 parganas
                </div>
                <p>
                    Area Description
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
                <div class="text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
                </div>
                <div class="btn">
                    <a href="#">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
                <div class="name">
                    North 24 parganas
                </div>
                <p>
                    Area Description
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
                <div class="text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
                </div>
                <div class="btn">
                    <a href="#">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are doing well.

I just reviewed your code snippet and updated your CSS. I hope it'll help you out. Thank You

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
html,body{
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background: #1d222b;
  text-align: center;
}
.container{
  padding: 0 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.card{
  height: 280px;
  max-width: 350px;
  margin: 0 20px 40px;
  background: white;
  transition: 0.4s;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  width: calc(20% - 40px);
}
.card:hover{
  height: 560px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.card .img{
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
.card .img img{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.card .top-text{
  padding: 5px;
}
.card .top-text .name{
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #202020;
}
.card .top-text p{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #007bff;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.card .bottom-text{
  padding: 0 20px 10px 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background: white;
  display: none;
  transition: 0.1s;
}
.card:hover .bottom-text{
  display: block;
}
.card .bottom-text .text{
  text-align: justify;
}
.card .bottom-text .btn{
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-align: left;
}
.card .bottom-text .btn a{
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #000;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-flex;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
.card .bottom-text .btn a:hover{
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 978px) {
  .container{
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .card{
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 20px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Tours</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="3destination_style.css">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                Barrackpore
               </div>
               <p>
                  Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    
         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                Hooghly
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                South 24 parganas 
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                North 24 parganas
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                Kolkata 
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                North 24 parganas
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                North 24 parganas
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                North 24 parganas
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                North 24 parganas
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                North 24 parganas
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                North 24 parganas
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                North 24 parganas
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                North 24 parganas
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                North 24 parganas
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                North 24 parganas
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                North 24 parganas
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                North 24 parganas
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card">
            <div class="img">
               <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/stamprsimp2red-vector-id1096052566?k=20&m=1096052566&s=612x612&w=0&h=CPU7LLHBwJm2OKoXCLxqKDzGaR0Xa1WGTQoryfdWQ3g=">
            </div>
            <div class="top-text">
               <div class="name">
                North 24 parganas
               </div>
               <p>
                Area Description
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-text">
               <div class="text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quaerat iusto adipisci reprehenderit quasi cum perspiciatis, minima reiciendis magni quam!
               </div>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```